# Create monero browser mining module

Tags: mining, development, python

I am a young programmer, still in college, interesting in creating a universal plug-in in python that I can apply to a few applications I have created. I would like to develop a python3 module that adopts user cpu threads, and uses the threads to mine cryptocurrency, monero specifically, whenever a user is active on my site, is this impossible to do without manually configuring a miner from user device?

Follow Up-- If I do not need to manually config, and include this in a terms & agreement can I run this module as long as a user access token remains valid?

Sidenote: I am not interested in using Coinhive

Comment: Do you intend to mine from a users browser or from a python application running on their computer?

Comment: A python file, browser mining is slow money haha, as proven by coinhive. Sorry for the late response!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, mining from a python script, your best bet is to build a [python c extension](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html).

You can include the relevant crypto hashing functions and take it from there. An example, albite a JS WASM module, is [here](https://github.com/jtgrassie/xmr-wasm/tree/master/src). Essentially rework the `main.cpp` as your python extension api.